# Git checkout to discard changes, ran from subdirectory, with entire project scope?

Tags: git

Say you have a git repo folder, at `/path/to/myrepo_git`. Say you have made changes in the working copy, in `/path/to/myrepo_git/a.txt`, `/path/to/myrepo_git/b.txt` and `/path/to/myrepo_git/subdir/c.txt`.

Now, say you want to discard those changes. If you're in the git repo root directory (here `/path/to/myrepo_git`), then this is straightforward:

```
user@PC:/path/to/myrepo_git $ git checkout -- .
```

However if you're in a subdirectory of the git repo folder, my guess is that first you'd have to get to the root of the git repo, before you can use `git checkout` to get rid of all changes, otherwise the `git checkout` will only get rid of the changes in the subdirectory - so for instance, you'd do:

```
user@PC:/path/to/myrepo_git/subdir $ cd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
user@PC:/path/to/myrepo_git $ git checkout -- .
user@PC:/path/to/myrepo_git $ cd subdir/  # to go back to where I was before
```

So, my question is - is there a single git command, so I can discard all changes in the working copy, even if I'm currently in a subdirectory (such that when the process is done, I'd still remain in the same subdirectory)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use any path for the `git checkout` command, so you could do

```sh
git checkout -- "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for that - I always had the impression that `checkout` only works with relative paths, so I was afraid to try absolute paths (as is the output of `rev-parse --show-toplevel`) with it `:)` Just tried this, seems to work fine - thanks!

Comment: @phd that usually works too *but* beware of the case where `--show-cdup` prints the empty string because you're already at the top level. I sometimes think it should print `.` for this case instead, as that works in more of the corner-case-y cases.